# Extract characters that differ between two strings

Tags: r, string, character

I have used `adist` to calculate the number of characters that differ between two strings:

```
a <- "Happy day"
b <- "Tappy Pay"
adist(a,b) # result 2
```

Now I would like to extract those character that differ. In my example, I would like to get the string `"Hd"` (or `"TP"`, it doesn't matter).

I tried to look in `adist`, `agrep` and `stringi` but found nothing.

Comment: I suggest you undo the edit and ask a new question.  In this new question you'll have to give much more information about your real data.  For example, it matters hugely whether you know that the different string is at the start vs. at the end of the string. You also have to tell us if your problem relates at all to the [longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Comment: Agreed, undo the edit, accept the best answer, and ask a new question.  The question is substantively different, and a lot of people have put in a lot of work already.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the following sequence of operations:

- split the string using `strsplit()`.
- Use `setdiff()` to compare the elements
- Wrap in a reducing function

Try this:

```
Reduce(setdiff, strsplit(c(a, b), split = ""))
[1] "H" "d"
```

Comment: `do.call(setdiff, strsplit(c(a, b), split = ""))` will be probably more efficient

Comment: Second arg to `strsplit` is `split` so you don't need to name it if you want to get down in fewer shots.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Not if you're playing code golf.  `Reduce` is one less keystroke than `do.call` :-)

Comment: @Spacedman As the number of answers to a programming question grows, the probability of it degenerating into code golf approaches 1.

Answer (score 7):

Split into letters and take the difference as sets:

```
> setdiff(strsplit(a,"")[[1]],strsplit(b,"")[[1]])
[1] "H" "d"
```

Answer (score 5):

Not really proud of this, but it seems to do the job:

```
sapply(setdiff(utf8ToInt(a), utf8ToInt(b)), intToUtf8)
```

Results:

```
[1] "H" "d"
```

Comment: That's a nice one. You could probably vectorize it by `intToUtf8(setdiff(utf8ToInt(a), utf8ToInt(b)))`

Comment: You might not be proud, but this helped my find a "non breaking space" instead of a regular space by comparing unicode integers.

Answer (score 4):

As long as `a` and `b` have the same length we can do this:

```
s.a <- strsplit(a, "")[[1]]
s.b <- strsplit(b, "")[[1]]
paste(s.a[s.a != s.b], collapse = "")
```

giving:

```
[1] "Hd"
```

This seems straightforward in terms of clarity of the code and seems tied for the fastest of the solutions provided here although I think I prefer `f3`:

```
f1 <- function(a, b)
  paste(setdiff(strsplit(a,"")[[1]],strsplit(b,"")[[1]]), collapse = "")

f2 <- function(a, b)
  paste(sapply(setdiff(utf8ToInt(a), utf8ToInt(b)), intToUtf8), collapse = "")

f3 <- function(a, b) 
  paste(Reduce(setdiff, strsplit(c(a, b), split = "")), collapse = "")

f4 <- function(a, b) {
  s.a <- strsplit(a, "")[[1]]
  s.b <- strsplit(b, "")[[1]]
  paste(s.a[s.a != s.b], collapse = "")
}

a <- "Happy day"
b <- "Tappy Pay"

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f1, f2, f3, f4, replications = 10000, order = "relative")[1:4]
```

giving the following on a fresh session on my laptop:

```
  test replications elapsed relative
3   f3        10000    0.07    1.000
4   f4        10000    0.07    1.000
1   f1        10000    0.09    1.286
2   f2        10000    0.10    1.429
```

I have assumed that the differences must be in the corresponding character positions.  You might want to clarify if that is the intention or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the variables as a regex character class and `gsub` out from the other one:

```
gsub(paste0("[",a,"]"),"",b)
[1] "TP"
gsub(paste0("[",b,"]"),"",a)
[1] "Hd"
```

Comment: Does that work if the strings have regexpy-special chars in them?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, good catch, special character class regex, such as `^` and `-` may cause issues. This could be a particular issue with hyphenated words.

Answer (score 1):

The following function could be a better option to solve problem like this.

```
list.string.diff <- function(a, b, exclude = c("-", "?"), ignore.case = TRUE, show.excluded = FALSE)
{
if(nchar(a)!=nchar(b)) stop("Lengths of input strings differ. Please check your input.")
if(ignore.case)
{
a <- toupper(a)
b <- toupper(b)
}
split_seqs <- strsplit(c(a, b), split = "")
only.diff <- (split_seqs[[1]] != split_seqs[[2]])
only.diff[
(split_seqs[[1]] %in% exclude) |
(split_seqs[[2]] %in% exclude)
] <- NA
diff.info<-data.frame(which(is.na(only.diff)|only.diff),
split_seqs[[1]][only.diff],split_seqs[[2]][only.diff])
names(diff.info)<-c("position","poly.seq.a","poly.seq.b")
if(!show.excluded) diff.info<-na.omit(diff.info)
diff.info
```

> from https://www.r-bloggers.com/extract-different-characters-between-two-strings-of-equal-length/

Then you can run

```
list.string.diff(a, b)
```

to get the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get the difference between two strings with the following code :

````
library(rmarkdown)
library(stringr)
library(diffr)
library(pagedown)
library(RDCOMClient)

print_Visual_File_Difference_Between_Text_To_Html <- function(text1, text2, output_Filepath)
{
  file1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".txt")
  writeLines(text1, con = file1)
  file2 <-  paste0(tempfile(), ".txt")
  writeLines(text2, con = file2)
  rmd_File <- tempfile(fileext = ".rmd")
  command_Diff <- paste0("diffr(", paste0("'", file1, "'"), ", ", paste0("'", file2, "'"), ", ", "before = 'Text 1', after = 'Text 2')")
  command_Diff <- str_replace_all(string = command_Diff, pattern = "\\\\", replacement = "/")

  rmd_Text <- c("---", "title: 'Text comparison between files'", "output: html_document",
                "---", "```{r file comparison, echo = FALSE}", "library(diffr)", command_Diff, "```")

  writeLines(rmd_Text, con = rmd_File)
  rmarkdown::render(rmd_File)
  rmd_Html  <- stringr::str_replace(string = rmd_File, pattern = "\\.rmd", replacement = "\\.html")
  file.copy(from = rmd_Html, to = output_Filepath)
}

setwd("C:\\")
text1 <- "Mon nom est Emmanuel Hamel. Mon adresse est le 324 jorge 1. Mon numéro de tel est 591-452-4000"
text2 <- "Mon nom est Emmanuel Hamel. Mon adresse est le xxxxxxx. Mon numéro de tel est xxxxxxx"
print_Visual_File_Difference_Between_Text_To_Html(text1, text2, output_Filepath = "comparaison.html")

IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate2("C:\\comparaison.html")
doc <- IEApp$Document()
web_Obj_Char_Delete <- doc$getElementsByClassName("char-delete")
web_Obj_Char_Insert <- doc$getElementsByClassName("char-insert")

> web_Obj_Char_Delete$Item(0)$innerText()
[1] "324 jorge 1"
> web_Obj_Char_Insert$Item(0)$innerText()
[1] "xxxxxxx"
> web_Obj_Char_Delete$Item(1)$innerText()
[1] "591-452-4000"
> web_Obj_Char_Insert$Item(1)$innerText()
[1] "xxxxxxx"
````

I used internet explorer to read the html file in local mode. Selenium could also be use. See : [Opening local HTML file using RSelenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760921/opening-local-html-file-using-rselenium/76019446#76019446)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach based on the Word software :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

path_To_File1 <- "C\\...\\file_1.docx"
path_To_File2 <- "C\\...\\file_2.docx"
path_To_File3 <- "C\\...\\file_3.docx"

text1 <- "Mon nom est Emmanuel Hamel. Mon adresse est le 324 jorge 1. Mon numéro de tel est 591-452-4000"
text2 <- "Mon nom est Emmanuel Hamel. Mon adresse est le xxxxxxx. Mon numéro de tel est xxxxxxx"

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
doc1 <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_File1))
doc1$Content()$InsertAfter(text = text1)
doc2 <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_File2))
doc2$Content()$InsertAfter(text = text2)
doc3 <- wordApp[["Application"]]$CompareDocuments(OriginalDocument = doc1, RevisedDocument = doc2)
nb_Revisions <- doc3$Revisions()$Count()

for(i in 1 : nb_Revisions)
{
  print(doc3$Revisions()$Item(i)$Range()$Text())
}

[1] "324 jorge 1"
[1] "xxxxxxx"
[1] "591-452-4000"
[1] "xxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer based on chatgpt :

```
library(chatgpt)
library(stringr)
question <- "What caracters differ between the text_1 and text_2. Only provide the caracter difference in the answer. 
             text_1 : Mon nom est Emmanuel Hamel. Mon adresse est le 324 jorge 1. Mon numéro de tel est 591-452-4000
             text_2 : Mon nom est Emmanuel Hamel. Mon adresse est le xxxxxxx. Mon numéro de tel est xxxxxxx"

Sys.setenv(OPENAI_API_KEY = "xxx")
chatgpt::reset_chat_session()
text <- ask_chatgpt(question)
text_Extracted <- unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(text, "(:.*\\(text_\\d\\))|(vs.*\\(text_\\d\\))"))
unlist(stringr::str_split(text_Extracted, "vs"))

[1] ": \"324 jorge 1\" (text_1) "  " \"xxxxxxx\" (text_2)" ": \"591-452-4000\" (text_1) " " \"xxxxxxx\" (text_2)"
```