# Extract distinct characters that differ between two strings

Tags: r, string

I have two strings, `a <- "AERRRTX"; b <- "TRRA"` .

I want to extract the characters in `a` not used in `b`, i.e. "ERX"

I tried the answer in [Extract characters that differ between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834459/extract-characters-that-differ-between-two-strings) , which uses `setdiff`. It returns "EX", because `b` does have "R" and `setdiff` will eliminate all three "R"s in `a`. My aim is to treat each character as distinct, so only two of the three R's in `a` should be eliminated.

Any suggestions on what I can use instead of `setdiff`, or some other approach to achieve my output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A different approach using `pmatch`,

```
a1 <- unlist(strsplit(a, ""))
b1 <- unlist(strsplit(b, "")) 

a1[!1:length(a1) %in% pmatch(b1, a1)]

 #[1] "E" "R" "X"
```

Another example,

```
a <- "Ronak";b<-"Shah"

a1 <- unlist(strsplit(a, ""))
b1 <- unlist(strsplit(b, ""))
a1[!1:length(a1) %in% pmatch(b1, a1)]

# [1] "R" "o" "n" "k"
```

Comment: Minor point: It's advisable to avoid assigning `c`, since it's a commonly used built-in function. If `c` is a variable defined in any enclosing environment, references to that identifier can bind to it, which can mess up a lot of code. For example, `do.call(c,...)` fails in this case.

Comment: Nice alternative. You could replace your third line with `a1[-pmatch(b1, a1)]`. Also, it would be useful to note the "duplicates.ok = FALSE" argument of `pmatch` which differentiates its behaviour to `match`

Answer (score 4):

We can use [`Reduce()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) to successively eliminate from `a` each character found in `b`:

```
a <- 'AERRRTX'; b <- 'TRRA';
paste(collapse='',Reduce(function(as,bc) as[-match(bc,as,nomatch=length(as)+1L)],strsplit(b,'')[[1L]],strsplit(a,'')[[1L]]));
## [1] "ERX"
```

This will preserve the order of the surviving characters in `a`.

---

Another approach is to mark each character with its occurrence index in `a`, do the same for `b`, and then we can use [`setdiff()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html):

```
a <- 'AERRRTX'; b <- 'TRRA';
pasteOccurrence <- function(x) ave(x,x,FUN=function(x) paste0(x,seq_along(x)));
paste(collapse='',substr(setdiff(pasteOccurrence(strsplit(a,'')[[1L]]),pasteOccurrence(strsplit(b,'')[[1L]])),1L,1L));
## [1] "ERX"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the function *vsetdiff* from *vecsets* package

```
install.packages("vecsets")
library(vecsets)
a <- "AERRRTX"
b <- "TRRA"  
Reduce(vsetdiff, strsplit(c(a, b), split = ""))
## [1] "E" "R" "X"
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using `data.table` package`:

```
library(data.table)

x = data.table(table(strsplit(a, '')[[1]]))
y = data.table(table(strsplit(b, '')[[1]]))

dt = y[x, on='V1'][,N:=ifelse(is.na(N),0,N)][N!=i.N,res:=i.N-N][res>0]

rep(dt$V1, dt$res)
#[1] "E" "R" "X"
```