# Row-wise extract characters that differ between two strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two columns of strings in a dataframe, and for each row I want to see the characters which differ.

E.g given

```
Lines <- "
a     b
cat   car
dog   ding
cow   haw"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

return

```
a     b     diff
cat   car   t
dog   ding  o
cow   haw   co
```

I have seen

> [Extract characters that differ between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834459/extract-characters-that-differ-between-two-strings)

as well as

> [Split comma-separated column into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773770/split-comma-separated-column-into-separate-rows/31514711#4919355)

where a number of neat solutions are returned, which would work for an individual row (first reference), or act row wise but not exactly what I want (second reference).

Ideally I'd like to use something like this:

```
Reduce(setdiff, strsplit(c(a, b), split = ""))
```

I tried:

```
apply(df, function(a,b) Reduce(setdiff, strsplit(c(a, b), split = "")))
```

but to no avail.

How can this be done?

p.s. I'm particularly keen to do this using dplyr if possible, but only for stylistic reasons

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Please consider using `dput`. For example, we will get to see if you actually have character vectors or factor in your columns, which is a common source of confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `df` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end define a function `Diff` which accepts two vecdors of strings, runs the setdiff on them and pastes the result together and then use `mapply` to run that on the two columns after splitting them into individual characters.

```
Diff <- function(x, y) paste(setdiff(x, y), collapse = "")
transform(df, diff = mapply(Diff, strsplit(a, ""), strsplit(b, "")))
```

giving:

```
    a    b diff
1 cat  car    t
2 dog ding    o
3 cow  haw   co
```

**Note:** The input `df` used above is:

```
Lines <- "
a     b
cat   car
dog   ding
cow   haw"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution from `tidyverse` and `stringr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(a_list = str_split(a, pattern = ""), b_list = str_split(b, pattern = "")) %>%
  mutate(diff = map2(a_list, b_list, setdiff)) %>%
  mutate(diff = map_chr(diff, ~paste(., collapse = ""))) %>%
  select_if(~!is.list(.))
dt2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b  diff
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1   cat   car     t
2   dog  ding     o
3   cow   haw    co
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "a     b
cat   car
                 dog   ding
                 cow   haw",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
ff = data.frame(a = c("dog","chair","love"),b = c("dot","liar","over"),stringsAsFactors = F)
st = ff %>% mutate(diff = sapply(Map(setdiff,strsplit(a,""),strsplit(b,"")),paste,collapse = ""))

> st
      a    b diff
1   dog  dot    g
2 chair liar   ch
3  love over    l
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R method using `Map`.

```
diffList <- Map(setdiff, strsplit(dat[[1]], ""), strsplit(dat[[2]], ""))
diffList
[[1]]
[1] "t"

[[2]]
[1] "o"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "o"
```

You can wrap this in `sapply` to return a character vector for your data.frame:

```
dat$charDiffs <-sapply(diffList, paste, collapse="")
```

which returns

```
dat
    a    b charDiffs
1 cat  car         t
2 dog ding         o
3 cow  haw        co
```

**data (from `dput`)**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(a = c("cat", "dog", "cow"), b = c("car", "ding", 
"haw")), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```