# Opening local HTML file using RSelenium

Tags: html, r, docker, rselenium

I'm trying to open a local HTML file using RSelenium.

I've been following this guide (https://callumgwtaylor.github.io/blog/2018/02/01/using-rselenium-and-docker-to-webscrape-in-r-using-the-who-snake-database/) and all seems to work except when I replace the URL with a local path, nothing loads. I tried turning the path into a link which also fails.

```
file:///C:/Users/Username/Desktop/file.html.
```

The html file contains data from reports that need scraping and the original isn't actually on the web.  I'm fairly new to scraping data so any help would be appreciated.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                      port = 4445L,
                      browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("http://apps.who.int/bloodproducts/snakeantivenoms/database/SearchFrm.aspx") #Entering our URL gets the browser to navigate to the page

remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE) #This will take a screenshot and display it in the RStudio viewer
```

Comment: I think `RSelenium` needs a proper web server to work. You can't read a local static file with it. You'll probably need to spin up a local webserver. The R package `servr` can probably help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to navigate to a local file with RSelenium with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
library(servr)

port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
pJS <- wdman::phantomjs(port = port)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = port)
remDr$open()

httd(dir = "D:\\")
remDr$navigate("⁠http://localhost:port/test_File.html")
remDr$screenshot(TRUE)
```

I also have been able to navigate a local html file with Internet explorer with the following code with the R package RDCOMClient. It is not with RSelenium, but I think this answer can be interesting for you.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate2("D:\\test_File.html")
```

Afterwards, with internet explorer, we can "webscrape" the file.